# Postgresql syntax error for where not exists

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following sql query that would only insert if it does not already exist in the table

```
INSERT INTO message_log (message, from_id, to_id, match_id, unix_timestamp, own_account) VALUES('hi', 'tom', 'tom', '55640ec48a2aecab0e3c096c556f5435f4bb054c68930040', 33333, TRUE)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM message_log WHERE message = 'hi' AND from_id = 'tom' AND to_id = 'tom' AND match_id = '55640ec48a2aecab0e3c096c556f5435f4bb054c68930040' AND unix_timestamp = 33333)
```

However I get the following error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE"
LINE 2: WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM message_log where message = ...
        ^
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: There is no `SELECT` in the query.

Comment: That is not something you can do. At least not like that. Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish with that `INSERT` statement?

Comment: @JNevill I want the row to be inserted only if it does not already exist in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inserting a record in a table only if that record doesn't exist is done with:

```
 INSERT INTO message_log (message, from_id, to_id, match_id, unix_timestamp, own_account) 
 SELECT 'hi', 'tom', 'tom', '55640ec48a2aecab0e3c096c556f5435f4bb054c68930040', 33333, TRUE
 FROM message_log
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM message_log WHERE message = 'hi' AND from_id = 'tom' AND to_id = 'tom' AND match_id = '55640ec48a2aecab0e3c096c556f5435f4bb054c68930040' AND unix_timestamp = 33333)
```

It's a little more verbose, but it should do what you want. Alternatively, you could set a unique primary key on the table, so the database will give you the smack-down if you try to insert a duplicate key. Six of one, half a dozen of the other.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do

```
INSERT INTO message_log (message, from_id, to_id, match_id, unix_timestamp, own_account)
SELECT 'hi', 'tom', 'tom', '55640ec48a2aecab0e3c096c556f5435f4bb054c68930040', 33333, TRUE
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM message_log WHERE message = 'hi' AND from_id = 'tom'
    AND to_id = 'tom' AND match_id = '55640ec48a2aecab0e3c096c556f5435f4bb054c68930040'
    AND unix_timestamp = 33333)
```

However it lacks styke: self query.

Maybe something like the following might be applicable:

```
INSERT ...
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE own_account = own_account;
```